# HTML Pug and SCSS Animation script not works in Chrome Browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, pug

I get this Boxes Animation script from Codepen but it not working in old Chrome browser version 49 or early version, Can anyone figure out why it is not working in old chrome browser like version 49?  however it is perfectly working in old firefox browser like version 52. even it is also working perfectly in new version of chrome browser. i am using Chrome 49 in windows xp. so it is not working in chrome 49. Xp not support above chrome 49 and firefox 52. So anyone please figure out why it is not working perfectly in old chrome browser like ver 49.

The script is built in Html(pug) and SCSS.

SCSS Code:

```
  $delay: 1250ms;
$duration: 6000ms;
$size: 25px;
$half: $size / 2;
$nalf: $size / -2;

$total-blocks: 50;

html, body {
   height: 100%; 
   margin: 0;
   overflow: hidden;
}

* {
   box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
   display: flex;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center; 
   background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #c6c6c6, #ffffff 10vh, #e7e7e7 10vh, #EEE);
}

.ready {
   display: grid;
   grid-gap: $size;
   grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
   
   animation: lateral $duration linear infinite both;
   animation-delay: $delay / 2;
}

.R { 
   grid-template-areas:
      "a1 a6 a8"
      "a2 . a9"
      "a3 a7 ."
      "a4 . a10"
      "a5 . a11";

   > :nth-child(8),
   > :nth-child(9) {
      top: $half;
      position: relative;
   }
   > :nth-child(10) {
      left: $nalf;
      position: relative;
   }
}

.E { 
   grid-template-areas:
      "a1 a6 a9"
      "a2 . ."
      "a3 a7 a10"
      "a4 . ."
      "a5 a8 a11";
}

.A { 
   grid-template-areas:
      ". a1 ."
      "a2 . a7"
      "a3 . a8"
      "a4 a6 a9"
      "a5 . a10";

   > :nth-child(2) {
      left: $half;
      position: relative;
   }
   > :nth-child(7) {
      left: $nalf;
      position: relative;
   }
}

.D { 
   grid-template-areas:
      "a1 a6 a8"
      "a2 . a9"
      "a3 . a10"
      "a4 . a11"
      "a5 a7 .";
   > :nth-child(n + 8) {
      top: $half;
      position: relative;
   }
}

.Y {
   grid-template-areas:
      "a1 . a6"
      "a2 . a7"
      "a3 . a8"
      ". a4 ."
      ". a5 .";

   > :nth-child(3) {
      left: $half;
      position: relative;
   }
   > :nth-child(8) {
      left: $nalf;
      position: relative;
   }
}

.letter {
   display: grid;
   grid-gap: 4px;
}

.block {
   --ratio: calc(var(--index) / #{$total-blocks});
   --delay: calc(calc(var(--ratio) * #{$delay / 2}) + #{$delay / 2}); 
     
   transform-style: preserve-3d; 
   transform: rotate(calc(var(--angle) * 1deg)) translate3d(calc(var(--sign) * 200vw), 0, 0) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -90deg) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 90deg);
   animation-name: block-intro;
   animation-timing-function: ease-in;  
   animation-fill-mode: both;
   animation-iteration-count: infinite;
   animation-delay: var(--delay);
   animation-direction: reverse;
   animation-duration: $duration;
   position: relative;
   z-index: -1;
   
   height: $size;
   width: $size;
   will-change: transform;

   .face {
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #2e92de;
      backface-visibility: visible;
      width: $size;
      height: $size;
      border: solid 1px #2f454f;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
   }

   .face-1 {
      transform-origin: bottom center;
   }

   .face-2 {
      transform: rotateX(-90deg);
      transform-origin: bottom center;
      overflow: hidden;
      
      &:before {
         content: '';
         position: absolute;
         background-color: #00d2ff99;
         top: 0;
         left: 0;
         right: 0;
         bottom: 0;
         animation: shimmer $duration linear;
         animation-delay: var(--delay);
         animation-fill-mode: both;
         animation-iteration-count: infinite;
      }
      // display: none;
   }
   .face-3 {
      transform: rotateY(90deg);
      transform-origin: right center;
      // display: none;
   }
}
 
@keyframes block-intro { 
   40%  {
      transform: rotate(0deg) translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -90deg) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 90deg);
      animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.95,.05,.8,.04);
   }
   70% { 
      transform: rotate(0deg) translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -90deg) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 90deg);
      animation-timing-function: linear;
   }
   80% { 
      transform: rotate(0deg) translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 0deg) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 0deg);
      animation-timing-function: linear;
   }
   100% {  
      transform: rotate(0deg) translate3d(150vw, 0, 0) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 0deg) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 0deg);
      animation-timing-function: ease-out;
   }
}

@keyframes lateral {
   from {
      transform: translateX(12%)
   }
   to {
      transform: translateX(-12%)
   }
}

@keyframes shimmer {
   from, 25% {
      transform: scale(2, 1) rotate(-45deg) translate(-100%);
   }
   35%, to {
      transform: scale(2, 1) rotate(-45deg) translate(0%);
   }
}
```

HTML Pug Code

```
.ready
   - var t = -1
   - var n = -1
   .letter.R
      while n++ < 10
        .block(style={ "--index": ++t, "--angle": (147 * t) % 360, "--sign": t % 2 ? 1 : -1, "grid-area": "a" + (n+1) })
          .face.face-1
          .face.face-2
          .face.face-3

   - n = -1;
   .letter.E
      while n++ < 10
        .block(style={ "--index": ++t, "--angle": (-147 * t) % 360, "--sign": t % 2 ? 1 : -1, "grid-area": "a" + (n+1) })
          .face.face-1
          .face.face-2
          .face.face-3

   - n = -1;
   .letter.A
      while n++ < 9
        .block(style={ "--index": ++t, "--angle": (147 * t) % 360, "--sign": t % 2 ? 1 : -1, "grid-area": "a" + (n+1) })
          .face.face-1
          .face.face-2
          .face.face-3
          
   - n = -1;
   .letter.D
      while n++ < 10
        .block(style={ "--index": ++t, "--angle": (-147 * t) % 360, "--sign": t % 2 ? 1 : -1, "grid-area": "a" + (n+1) })
          .face.face-1
          .face.face-2
          .face.face-3
          
   - n = -1;
   .letter.Y
      while n++ < 7
        .block(style={ "--index": ++t, "--angle": (147 * t) % 360, "--sign": t % 2 ? 1 : -1, "grid-area": "a" + (n+1) })
          .face.face-1
          .face.face-2
          .face.face-3
```

Please Fix this Code to run in old Chrome Browser like version 49.

The source for this script is from Codepen:

https://codepen.io/notoriousb1t/pen/vroZox

Thanks

Comment: _"Please Fix this Code to run in Chrome Browser"_ - how is it broken?

Comment: Actually it is not working in old version of chrome browser like ver 49? however it is perfectly working in old firefox browser like version 52. even it is also working perfectly in new version of chrome browser. i am using Chrome 49 in windows xp. so it is not working in chrome 49. and Xp not support above chrome 49 and firefox 52. So anyone please figure out why it is not working perfectly in old chrome browser like ver 49.